# angularjs modify date (not date obj) in div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Lets say i have a div

```
<div class="date-display">{{date.displayModofiedDate}}</div>
```

that is receiving an object that looks like this: `SUNDAY 25` or `TUESDAY 12` but it is not a date object. How can I get the weekdays to be only 3 letters long? So that it looks like `MON 25` or `WED 02`

I can't to `| date: 'EEE dd'` because it's not a date object, and `limitTo` wont work either, because I ened the numbers at the end of the string.

Comment: seems like a case for a regex.

Comment: [or substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: Create your own filter that split() string by space, substring() the first value and join() the array.

Answer (score 1):

if the string always come that format then you can create a custom filter like this to return string

```
.filter('dateTime',function($filter){
  return function(obj){
    var arr = obj.split(" ")
    return arr[0].substring(0, 3) +" "+ arr[1];
  }
})
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.name = ["SUNDAY 12","TUESDAY 10","MONDAY 12"];
})
.filter('dateTime',function($filter){
  return function(obj){
    var arr = obj.split(" ")
    return arr[0].substring(0, 3) +" "+ arr[1];
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in name" > {{item | dateTime}}

  </div>
</div>
```